# Can I get all of the possible options of a model's field using the django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a model with a char field 'year'. Is there a way that I can get a list of all of the years that are used by objects in this table? Essentially, if there are objects with years 2008, 2009, 2010, and 2011, I want a list [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011]. Is this functionality present in the ORM, or would I have to write a custom function (which I can do, though I'd rather not reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('year', flat=True).distinct()
```